# Generate all possible binary matrices of size N x M (Python)

Tags: python, matrix, combinations

I know there's other questions similar to this out there which generate matrices with some properties, but I'm looking to generate all possible matrices of a given size with no restrictions other than the entries being either a 1 or a 0 in Python. How can I do this?

Comment: [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: I find this solution more readable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924059/4816158

Comment: This answer is more readable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924059/4816158

Answer (score 2):

I did it in one line (just kidding)

```
def gen(n, m): 
    for i in range(2**(n*m)): 
        yield np.array([int(k) for k in "{0:b}".format(i).zfill(n*m)]).reshape(n,m)
```

The way this works is kind of a hack, I count in binary and fill the array with the bits.

If you're not familiar with generators/iterators, just look at how to use it:

```
for mat in gen(3, 5): pass   # mat goes threw every possible array (uses virtually no memory)
l = list(gen(3, 5))          # array of all possible arrays (uses a lot of memory)
```