# Python generate all possible combinations of matrix

Tags: python, list, math, combinations

I need to generate all combinations of a matrix in Python. The input will be two integers n and m, and I need to generate all possible states of that matrix with 1 and 0 as possible values.

For example:

```
n = 3 m = 2
[[0 0 0] [1 0 0] [1 1 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0],[0 0 0],[0 0 0] . . . . .
]
```

Is there a clean and efficient way to do this given I will not know the values for n and m until runtime? The highest value used will be n = 16  m = 16.

Comment: There will be 2^(nm) outputs. There is no faster way then to enumerate every single one of them. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: it may be worth asking whether you need those matrices, or if they are some intermediate state to something else. if the latter, you can optimise it in that way

Comment: Sorry yes the integers are the rows and columns. Until now I knew the values before runtime so was simply using two nested loops but this isn't feasible anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is by generating all binary sequences of length `m*n` in a list comprehension, and reshaping them into a `(m,n)` shaped nested list on each iteration.

A simple way to generate all sequences is by taking the cartesian product of `01` with `n*m` repeats, which will be produce `2^(m*n)` combinations:

```
from itertools import product
m=3
n=3

x = [[list(i[x:x+m]) for x in range(0, len(i), m)] for i in product("01", repeat=m*n)]
```

**Output**

```
[[['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '0']]

 [['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '1']]

 [['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '0' '0']
  ['0' '1' '0']]
 ...

print(len(x))
# 512
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want all matrices at once, just produce flat lists using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) them:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

n, m = 2, 2

x = product([1, 0], repeat=n*m)
x = np.reshape(list(x), (-1, n, m))
print(x)
```

With the output for 2x2:

```
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]])
```

---

Note that for `n, m = 16, 16` there are `2**(16*16)` combinations, which is about `10**77`, so much too large to fit into memory. In that case you probably have to process each matrix on its own:

```
def get_combinations(n, m):
    for flat in product([1, 0], repeat=n*m):
        yield np.reshape(flat, (n, m))
```

Which you can use like this:

```
from itertools import islice

for m in islice(get_combinations(3, 3), 3):  # only get the first three
    print(m)

[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 0]]
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 0 1]]
```

Comment: @yatu: Fixed using `itertools.product` like you, but still using `numpy.reshape` instead of multiple calls to `numpy.array` and `numpy.array_split`.

Comment: Ended up going with a non-numpy solution, nice one @Graipher +1