# Python generate all possible combinations of matrix with diagonal entries zero

Tags: python, matrix, combinations

I'm a graph theorist and beginner in Python.

Similar to the following question,

[Python generate all possible combinations of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923928/python-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-matrix)

I need to generate all possible combinations of matrices with -1 and 1, but here, ***the diagonal entries are all zero***. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix"? Lists of lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: Can't you just use the accepted answer on that question using `m` and `n-1` and add zeroes when you reshape?

Comment: can we see what kind of output you're expecting?

Comment: @John Coleman... numpy arrays. Just like the code in the link which I put.

Comment: That is the best choice, but that question itself was posed in terms of lists of lists.

Comment: What's the size of matrix?

Comment: @John Coleman... ok. as lists of lists. No different

Comment: @TJC World...any size. Obviously, it is square matrix

Comment: Numpy arrays are the best for most mathematical purposes, and there is a difference both in the sort of code you would use and how efficient the resulting code would be. You didn't specify, so I asked. The question you linked to could be interpreted in either ways. In any event, @Chris has suggested a viable strategy for tweaking the code in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way, but this should work.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

sq_dim = 3

all_x = product([1, -1], repeat=sq_dim**2)
all_x = np.reshape(list(all_x), (-1, sq_dim, sq_dim))

for x in all_x:
    np.fill_diagonal(x, 0)

solution = np.unique(all_x, axis=0)
```